# Uncheck on Checkbox won't fire OnCheckedChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, devexpress

The following code will only fire in c# when the checkbox is checked. Not when it is unchecked again. Why is that?

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="cbEmail" ClientInstanceName ="cbEmailI" runat="server" CheckState="Unchecked" Text="Hello"  OnCheckedChanged ="onCheckChangedCBEmail" AutoPostBack="true" Width="181px"> 
     <ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="OnValueChangedEmail"  Init="OnValueChangedEmail" /></dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

**C#:**

```
 protected void onCheckChangedCBEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        bool isEmailChecked = cbEmail.Checked;
    }
```

`isEmailChecked` does get set to true when the checkbox is checked, however once it is unchecked it is not set to false. When debugging `onCheckChangedCBEmail(s,e)` is not even called when the checkbox is unchecked.

DevExpress is being used.

Comment: it seems a thirdpaarty control. What control are you using ?

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry it is DevExpress.

Comment: I would check to make sure you don't have validation kicking off somewhere that's preventing the postback.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I added a break point for Page_load and it seems like when unchecked it does hit Page_load again. Does that mean postback is occurring?

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai: Yes, if you're hitting the `Page_Load` event after toggling the checkbox, then the postback is occurring. In which case, I would make sure you're not resetting the checked state in your code somewhere.

Comment: @JamesJohnson if I watch checkbox.Checked in debug, it actually changes from true to false when unchecked. It just does not hit the OnCheckChangedCBEmail() method.

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai: Did you set a breakpoint on the changed event handler too? Because it will get called after `Page_Load`.

Comment: @JamesJohnson Yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Try settings its property `processOnServer` to `true`

### Update

Add watch to the checked property of the check where its get cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```

On your CheckBox. this will cause a new call to Page_Load();

Or you can use a callbackpanel like this.

```
     <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="CallBackPanel" lientInstanceName="CallBackPanel">
                <PanelCollection>
                    <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent" runat="server">

                                    <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="checkboxid" runat="server" Text="Some Text"                                     OnValueChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="False" >
                                        <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="function(s,e){CallBackPanel.PerformCallback();}"/>
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                    </dx:PanelContent>
                </PanelCollection>
            </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

And Server Side:

```
 protected void CheckedChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
```